# Setting up a cascading trigger on a parent table

Tags: trigger, postgresql-9.5

Let's say I have started to keep a log of all the postcards that I send so I define the table `postcards`:

```
                                            Table "postcards"
       Column         |            Type             |                Modifiers                 | Storage
----------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------
postcard_code         | bigint                      | not null                                 | plain    
postcard_recipient    | character varying(750)      | not null                                 | extended 
date_posted           | timestamp without time zone |                                          | plain    

Triggers:
    insert_date_posted BEFORE INSERT ON postcards FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_date_posted()
    update_date_posted BEFORE UPDATE ON postcards FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_date_posted()

Child tables:
    postcards_unsent,
    postcards_2018,
    postcards_2019,
    postcards_2020
```

Because of the amount of postcards that I plan to send I have set up partitions via table inheritance so that all the postcards that I send this year will be logged in `postcards_2018` and so on. The child tables are defined as, for example:

```
                                            Table "postcards_2018"
       Column         |            Type             |                Modifiers                 | Storage  
----------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+----------
postcard_code         | bigint                      | not null                                 | plain    
postcard_recipient    | character varying(750)      | not null                                 | extended 
date_posted           | timestamp without time zone |                                          | plain    

Indexes:
    "postcards_2018_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ( postcard_code, postcard_recipient )

Check constraints:
    "postcards_2018_date_posted_check" CHECK (
    date_posted >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND
    date_posted < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone )

Inherits: postcards
```

Everytime I buy a new postcard and send it, I add it to the table using:

```
INSERT INTO postcards ( postcard_code, postcard_recipient, date_posted )
VALUES ( 1, 'Adam', current_date );
```

The trigger `insert_date_posted` calls the trigger procedure `insert_date_posted()` and writes the row in the correct partition.
The trigger procedure `insert_date_posted()` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_date_posted()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.date_posted IS NULL ) THEN
        INSERT INTO postcards_unsent VALUES ( NEW.* );
    IF ( NEW.date_posted  >= '2018-01-01' AND NEW.date_posted < '2019-01-01') THEN
        INSERT INTO postcards_2018 values ( NEW.* );
    ELSIF ( NEW.date_posted  >= '2019-01-01' AND NEW.date_posted < '2020-01-01') THEN
        INSERT INTO postcards_2019 values ( NEW.* );
    ELSIF ( NEW.date_posted  >= '2020-01-01' AND NEW.date_posted < '2021-01-01') THEN
        INSERT INTO postcards_2020 values ( NEW.* );
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date out of range. Check postcards_insert_trigger() procedure.';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I add the trigger using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_date_posted
BEFORE INSERT
ON postcards
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_date_posted();
```

I also have a backlog of postcards that I want to send when I get around to it. I add them to the table and set `date_posted` to `NULL` to keep track of them. When I eventually do get around to sending a postcard from the backlog, I want to update the `date_posted` column using:

```
UPDATE postcards
SET date_posted = current_date
WHERE postcard_code = x
AND postcard_recipient = y
AND date_posted IS NULL;
```

I want the trigger `update_date_posted` to call the trigger procedure `update_date_posted()` that will:

- copy the row to the correct partition
- delete the row from the `postcards_unsent` partition
- trigger the `insert_date_posted` trigger.

The trigger procedure `update_date_posted()` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_date_posted()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ( OLD.date_posted IS NULL )
    THEN
        -- Copy this row to the right partition by assigning a non NULL date_posted value to it
        INSERT INTO postcards (
            postcard_code
            , postcard_recipient
            , date_posted )
        SELECT
            OLD.postcard_code
            , OLD.postcard_recipient
            , current_date
        FROM postcards
        WHERE ( date_posted IS NULL )
        AND postcard_code = OLD.postcard_code
        AND postcard_recipient = OLD.postcard_recipient
        -- Delete original entry to prevent duplication
        DELETE FROM postcards
        WHERE ( date_posted IS NULL )
        AND postcard_code = OLD.postcard_code
        AND postcard_recipient = OLD.postcard_recipient
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I then add this trigger using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_date_posted
BEFORE UPDATE
ON postcards
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_date_posted();
```

This does not work and the `update_date_posted` never gets called, the row is not copied to the `postcards_2018` partition, it is not deleted from the `postcards_unsent` partition and the `insert_date_posted` trigger is not called either.

The error message I see is:

```
ERROR: new row for relation "postcards_unsent" violates check constraint "postcards_unsent_date_posted_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ( x, y, current_date )
```

The `postcards_unsent_date_posted_check` constraint is:

```
Check constraints:
    "postcards_unsent_date_posted_check" CHECK ( date_posted  IS NULL )
```

It would appear as if the check constraint is executed first but I am not sure if that is the case and I don't see why this is not working.

Comment: Somehow I'm missing a link. I cannot see any update or insert for `postcards_unsent` apart from the insert in `insert_date_posted()`. The latter cannot cause the constraint violation as it's only executed when `NEW.date_posted IS NULL`. But I also see no delete for that table. But you want to delete there, so there must be a `DELETE FROM postcards_unsent` somewhere. Can you give me a pointer of have you forgotten to post some parts (here, not in snail mail ;))?

Comment: @stickybit The `INSERT INTO` and `DELETE` statements are in the `update_date_posted()` trigger procedure and the idea is that the trigger is applied to the parent table and not on the child tables.

Answer (score 2):

We got *some* clarity on what the issue here was and I am finally getting around to posting this. It boils down to how triggers behave in combination with partitions (and indirectly, inheritance ?) and the clue was in the [docs (5.10.6. Caveats)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html) relating to partitioning:

> The schemes shown here assume that the partition key column(s) of a
>   row never change, or at least do not change enough to require it to
>   move to another partition. An UPDATE that attempts to do that will
>   fail because of the CHECK constraints. If you need to handle such
>   cases, you can put suitable update triggers on the partition tables [...]

With our trigger, defined on the parent table, we were attempting to update the column `date_posted` which is the partition key and as per the snippet from the docs above, the `CHECK` constraint kept failing. When we defined the trigger to the child tables, it functioned as expected.

It did not occur to me sooner to try and define the trigger on the child tables as I was under the impression that `FOR EACH ROW` `BEFORE` triggers were not allowed on child tables.

We are using version 9.5 and my senior mentioned that this changes in the subsequent releases. I cloned the PostgreSQL Git repository and checked the commit logs for any clues and found:

- https://github.com/Aloisius/postgresql/commit/86f575948c773b0ec5b0f27066e37dd93a7f0a96

This commit states that:

> Previously, FOR EACH ROW triggers were not allowed in partitioned
>       tables.  Now we allow AFTER triggers on them, and on trigger creation we
>       cascade to create an identical trigger in each partition.

Except we used row level (`FOR EACH ROW`) `BEFORE` triggers and the version 10 [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/trigger-definition.html) state that:

> These types of triggers may only be defined on non-partitioned tables
>   [...]

However, the version 9.5 and version 9.6 [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/trigger-definition.html) say:

> These types of triggers may only be defined on tables [...]

Hence, we only got *some* clarity. In the meantime, the trigger works.